# How split the grid of Zurb Foundation with custom percentage?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using 12 column grid of Zurb Foundation to split the layout of the website.  As per the PSD design, I need to split the row into two columns - 20% and 80%.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to split the row – and not just use columns inside a row?

If it is an option to you, you could simply just change the 12 column grid to a 10 column grid.

Using Foundation SASS, simply change this

```
$total-columns: 12;
```

to

```
$total-columns: 10;
```

in `_settings.scss`

Now you have a 10 column grid, and making 20% | 80% columns are at your disposal. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="side">
.
.
.
   </div>
   <div class="main">
.
.
.
   </div>
```

css

```
.side{
 width:20%;
}
.main{
width:80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited the question again.  Do you know how to do this in Zurb Foundation?

Comment: if u want to do it with zurb use your own classes.
Or use 10 column grid structure by customizing foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this ( aside from just using your own classes as mentioned above ) is to target foundation's built in columns within your unique container.

```
<div id="unique-container">
  <div class="large-2 columns">
  <!--  your code -->
  </div>
  <div class="large-10 columns">
  <!--  your code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#unique-container.large-2 {
  width: 20%;
}

#unique-container.large-10 {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Hope this helps.